# C# using virtual-override

Tags: c#, polymorphism

In this example it uses polymorphysm via virtual, override keywords

```
 abstract class A
    {
        public virtual string Print() { return "A"; }
    }
    
    class B : A
    {
        public override string Print() { return "B"; }
    }
    
    class C : B
    {
        public virtual new string Print() { return "C"; }
    }
    
    class D : C
    {
        public override string Print() { return "D"; }
    }
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new D();
    
            Console.WriteLine(a.Print());
        }
    }
```

Console prints B. Why B, not D? Thank you for answers

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((a as D).Print())`

Comment: Whoever think it's a good question consider it's reposted typical [quiz question](https://codegalaxy.io/courses/csharp/questions/c2cbcce9d7d444ed9eccb1952331ed74/public-abstract-class-a-public-virtual-string-print-return-a-public-class-b-a-pu), without any research attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, because the last time you override the `Print` function of class `A` is during the declaration of class `B`

```
    class B : A
    {
        public override string Print() { return "B"; }
    }
```

By declaring `public virtual new`, you are hiding the underlying implementation of `Print`. So during the `D` declaration you are overriding the new implementation, declared at class `C`

Now `A`, has no knowledge whatsoever of what you've done, once you've hidden the function on `B`

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with methods that hide methods of their parent classes. It is not polymorphic. Since the variable is of type `A` the resolution of method Print() only knows about A.Print() and B.Print().
C.Print() and D.Print() are not overrides of A.Print(), because of the declation of C.Print() with `new`.